# I'm trying to search through the security logs for lockout events. Where am I getting my error?

Tags: security, powershell

```
 Get-Eventlog –ComputerName     
([System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()).FindDomainController()   
“Security” -InstanceID “4740″ -Message 
 *”Username"* | fl -Property timegenerated, message
```

I keep getting a terminator error when trying to run this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know that Get-Eventlog accepts that object as valid for the -ComputerName parameter. You may want to try `(([System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()).FindDomainController()).Name`. Also, did you mean `"*Username*"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by a "terminator error," but you need to pass the **name** of a computer into the `-ComputerName` parameter. The `FindDomainController()` method returns a `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DomainController` object. Instead of passing that object directly into the `-ComputerName` parameter, you instead need to reference the `Name` property of that class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domaincontroller(v=vs.110).aspx

Additionally, it looks like your script has "smart quotes" in it, which will often break your script. Replace the "smart quotes" with regular double or single quotes.

Here is a three-line script that ought to work:

```
$ComputerName = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain().FindDomainController().Name;
$EventList = Get-Eventlog –ComputerName $ComputerName -LogName "Security" -InstanceID 4740 -Message *Username*;
$EventList | Format-List -Property TimeGenerated,Message;
```

Comment: thanks for the post. I'm just teaching myself powershell at my internship to help out. What if I wanted to just test this out on my local machine before I run it on the domain? 

I don't think I can just replace the entire first line with $ComputerName = mycomputernamehere

Comment: Yes, you can simply update the value of the `$ComputerName` variable, to test it on your local computer. However, on a Windows client, you're not going to have the lock-out events you're searching for.